# Skip a component based on condition in Talend

Tags: talend

I have a scenario where I would like to skip a component to execute based on the condition and run its consecutive components in Talend.

Is it at all possible?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your job. Depending on what you're doing with your job you can conditionally execute subjobs using the `Run if` connector (rather than `Main` or `on Subjob Okay`).

Comment: You are right. I can put conditional dependency using Run If connector. If the condition satisfies the component will execute, but if not then I would like to skip that component and go to its next component.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your job (and further screenshots of anywhere important) so we can see how best to do this? I can think of a few options but it depends on what you're doing with the job.

Comment: we have to do something similar, the scenario is the following: Drop Schema Cascade -> Create Schema -> Subjob ( Drop table, create table) -> load data into tables, we want to have a DROP_SCHEMA boolean in the context, thus the first component needs to be executed when DROP_SCHEMA = 1 else it needs to be skipped.

Comment: As exactly as Balazs mentioned.  
Consider the task here as  
  
Pre_Job --> condition evaluation --> tSystem1 --> tSystem2  
  
If the condition in the variable is all then the natural flow like tSystem1 and then tSystem2.  
  
But if the condition in the variable saya tSystem2 then skip tSystem1 and execute tSystem2 alone.  

I could'nt post any screen shots. so just explained figuratively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've mocked up a job for you:

I have a context variable called: startFrom
It can be accessed with context.startFrom

I've placed a tJava with a few tWarns:
[image: full overview of the job]

I use 4 context settings:

1. Default
2. Normal
3. Opt
4. two

So my Job:

1. Does nothing
2. Start from "Start"
3. Start from "Optional_Start"
4. Start from "RecoverFromHere"

If settings are the following:

> context.startFrom.equals("opt")

Recovery and Recovery1 prints out their names using System.out

If I start my job I can select where I want to start it. If I don't select anything: context value is null, it won't do anything.

[image: opt]
[image: normal]
[image: two]

Comment: This is what I was expecting, thanks for the idea. Modified it a bit to make the run dynamic.

Answer (score 5):

You have two options available to you for conditionally executing parts of your job.

Where the component that follows your conditional check can be a starting component (if you drop it to the canvas then it should have a green background) then you can use the `Run if` connector to link it to the previous part of your job like so:

[image: Run If Job Setup]

In this example we simply call another tJava component conditionally but this could be any component that is startable.

Where the first tJava component (Set condition boolean) is configured with the following code:

```
Boolean condition = false;
globalMap.put("condition",condition);
```

And the two `Run if` connectors are set as `((Boolean)globalMap.get("condition")) == true` and `((Boolean)globalMap.get("condition")) == false` respectively.

A better option may be to use the filtering in a tMap or tFilterRow component and this also allows you to link to components that aren't starting components. To do this you would set your job up as below:

[image: tMap Conditional Job Setup]

In this job I have hard coded some tabular data in a tFixedFlowInput component:

[image: tMap Conditional Job Data]

We then use a tMap to filter the flows of data to any following components:

[image: tMap Conditional Job Data tMap configuration]

In which we test the value of the boolean condition column of our data. As an illustration I have also applied some simple, conditional transformation to the data where "true" rows have 1000 added to their value and "false" rows have 100 subtracted from their value.

From here you can then carry on the flow of your job as normal, in this case we link to a tSystem component to execute system commands as per your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can not use prejob as it does not have runif trigger, but you can do like this
prejob -->oncomponentok-->tJava (in here you poupulate you evaluate your condition say as given below)---->RUN IF Trigger - you put your condition here..((String)globalMap.get("var_myCondition")).equals("true") --->component to run in true condition
--->RUN IF Trigger on (tJava) ---((String)globalMap.get("var_myCondition")).equals("false")--->component to run in false condition


in short your job would be like 

prejob-->tJava---(RUNIF TRIGGER)------>component/flow to run in true condition
              ---(RUNIF TRIGGER)------>component/flow to run in false condition


tJava code 
String myCondition="false";
globalMap.put("var_myCondition",myCondition);
```